# C++ same object in two different vectors

Tags: c++, object, vector, duplicates

I'm working on a C++ project and I wonder if it's possible to store the same object in two different vector. I know how to deal with it in C with pointer, so you reference the same object to both table, but I'm little bit confused in C++.

If I create an object and I store it in vector a and in vector b. Do C++ copy the object or it's the same on both vector and if I modify one, the other is modified too ? In the second case, does it take more place to store it twice (for accessibility issues) or it's not a good way to deal with it ?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a pointer it will get modified everywhere.

Comment: That's the problem. I use std::vector and object. I don't really know how it works in C++.

Comment: If you do not know how a pointer works, then you should read a book or tutorial first... without pointers you won't get any far.

Comment: I think I was unclear in my post. I know well the C language and the pointer. Maybe I'm wrong but I was told pointer are not used in C++ language. I wonder how C++ deal with object (are object implicit pointers or something) ?

Comment: @romz34 why is that a problem? You said you want the same object, so if you modify it somewhere, you should see the modified object elsewhere

Comment: @romz34 pointer ARE used in C++

Comment: @Miki That's not a problem. I just wanted to understand C++ behaviour and answer here are often really good and well explained ;). That's why I'm asking for C++ programmer who know how this works.

Comment: @romz34 "I was told pointer are not used in C++ language" – that's wrong. There are pointers in C++, and they are used extensively. Whoever told you that pointers are not in C++ has obviously no idea what he is doing and you should never ever listen to him/her with regards to programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is a great place to check exactly this type of questions. Let me quote the relevant parts of the link:

> void push_back( const T& value );
>
> void push_back( T&& value );
>
> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
>
> 2) value is moved into the new element.

So yes, storing the same element twice in two vectors will cause it to get copied twice. You should use `std::vector<T*>` if you don't want to waste memory. And as always, you should also consider smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr` / `std::weak_ptr`) instead of naked pointers.

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to C, really.

If what you have is a `vector<object>`, then you'll be working with different objects.

On the other hand, a `vector<object*>` ensures that you'll only be storing pointers to your objects and then having multiple vectors containg the same object or objects is not an issue.

You might also consider using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` to simplify memory management when working with pointers in C++.

Answer (score 2):

When you insert an object into a `std::vector` a copy of it is made:

```
Foo a;
std::vector<Foo> vec1;
std::vector<Foo> vec2;
vec1.push_back(a); //copy made
vec2.push_back(b); //copy made
```

If you do not want a copy, you can either use pointers or `std::reference_wrapper` (you can't use references as they don't fulfil constraints on container value types):

```
Foo a;
std::vector<Foo*> vec1;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> vec2;
vec1.push_back(&a); //no copy
vec2.push_back(std::ref(b)); //no copy
```

Of course, now no need to ensure that the lifetime of `a` is no shorter than that of the vectors, otherwise you're on the fast-track to undefined behaviour.

You could also use `std::shared_ptr` which will ensure that your object is destructed when there are no more references to it:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> a = std::make_shared<Foo>();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> vec1;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> vec2;
vec1.push_back(a); //reference count incremented
vec2.push_back(a); //reference count incremented
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example for you:

```
class SomeObject { public: int a; };

int main()
{
    SomeObject some_object;
    some_object.a = 1;

    //Copies are made
    std::vector<SomeObject> foo;
    foo.push_back(some_object);

    std::vector<SomeObject> bar;
    bar.push_back(some_object);

    foo.at(0).a = 2;
    bar.at(0).a = 3;

    std::cout << foo.at(0).a << ' ' << bar.at(0).a;

    //Refers to the same object
    std::vector<SomeObject*> baz;
    baz.push_back(&some_object);

    std::vector<SomeObject*> foobar;
    foobar.push_back(&some_object);

    baz.at(0)->a = 4;
    foobar.at(0)->a = 5;

    std::cout << ' ' << baz.at(0)->a << ' ' << foobar.at(0)->a;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2 3 5 5
```